# Why textbox prevent div to be closed?

Tags: c#, html, textbox

I have a page with a food table, and when I want to add a new food, I have a button of "insert food", which when clicked shows a small div with labels, text-boxes and stuff for insertion, and it changes its text from "insert" to "cancel". Here is the code:

```
 protected void insertFoodBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (insertFoodBTN.Text == "Insert Food")
    {
        nameF.Visible = true;
        nameFTB.Visible = true;
        priceF.Visible = true;
        priceFTB.Visible = true;
        ... etc ...
        addFBTN.Visible = true;
        insertDiv.Style["display"] = "block";
        insertFoodBTN.Text = "Cancel Insertion";
    }
    else
    {
        nameF.Visible = false;
        nameFTB.Visible = false;
        priceF.Visible = false;
        priceFTB.Visible = false;
        ... etc ...
        addFBTN.Visible = false;
        insertDiv.Style["display"] = "none";
        insertFoodBTN.Text = "Insert Food";
    }
}
```

**That works fine**
My problem is that when I want to close it back by clicking the same "insert food" button it doesn't even enter the function of that insertButton_Clicked.
Notice - its text is "cancel insertion", but the ID hasn't been changed so it should basically enter.

After enquiring - it turns that the two first text boxes cause that, because when I deleted them the Insert div was gone again, as before.
I don't know why, because I have another text box after them which doesn't prevent hiding the div back.

I don't have a clue why is that. Thanks for helping.

[after clicking "Insert food" for the first time, and the div opens][1]

Comment: Do you dynamically add/remove text boxes in code? That could mess up the event handlers. If that's not it, I fear you will have to go through the work of creating a [mcve].

Comment: I simply add lables and text-boxes at the aspx file with visibility=false, and my intention is to dynamically change its visibility at the C# file after each time I press the button.

<div runat="server" id="insertDiv" style="display:none; text-align:left !important">
        <h1>Food</h1>
        <asp:Label ID="nameF" runat="server" Text="Name" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="nameFTB" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: I see. That should work. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I understood the problem. It is written down in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a div try surrounding your form with a Panel.
And instead of one button use two.

```
protected void insertFoodBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnInsert.Visible = true; 
    cancelFoodBTN.Visible = true;
    insertFoodBTN.Visble = false;
}


protected void cancelFoodBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnInsert.Visible = false;
    cancelFoodBTN.Visible = false;
    insertFoodBTN.Visble = true;
}
```

Comment: Actually, now I understand what was wrong. I have validators on those text boxes and when I open the div / panel, when they are active, they prevent me from going to the server and ignore my click. How can I overcome the validators?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was mainly the validators but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Since you state in the comments that the validators prevent the form from being submitted, the solution is to [enable/disable validation for the button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx) when its role changes:

```
protected void insertFoodBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (insertFoodBTN.Text == "Insert Food")
    {
        ...
        insertFoodBTN.Text = "Cancel Insertion";
        insertFootBTN.CausesValidation = false; // Cancel button does not require valid data
    }
    else
    {
        ...
        insertFoodBTN.Text = "Insert Food";
        insertFootBTN.CausesValidation = true;
    }
}
```

Note: Since the button has *two* different functions, I would suggest to create *two* buttons instead, only one of which is visible at a given time. That way, you don't have to "reconfigure" your button every time (which also causes you to duplicate things such as the button text in your ASP.NET markup as well as in your code, violating the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it soon but it seems to solve my problem.